# Add cells in row of table html

Tags: php, sql

I want to add row to my html table. I have the data of my table in my SQL query and visualize table in PHP.
My table have this structure:

`Product|Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6`

My problem is: for any product I can have one or plus data of other column and I want to add this data in the true column.

Ex: If for the Product 1 I have a data from Column1, Column3 and Column5 I want to add this data in true column:

```
Product  |Column1 |Column2|Column3 |Column4|Column5 |Column6

Product 1|ProdCol1|   0   |ProdCol3|   0   |ProdCol5|   0
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: use if the condition for all columns eg. if Column1 have data show else 0

Comment: @ZaheerAhmad can you show me an example?

Comment: $html_body = "";
for ($x = 0; $x <= data.length; $x++) {
    $html_body .= "<tr><td>".($data[$x]['column1'] ? $data[$x]['column1'] : 0)."</td><td>".($data[$x]['column2'] ? $data[$x]['column2'] : 0)."</td><td>".($data[$x]['column3'] ? $data[$x]['column3'] : 0)."</td><td>".($data[$x]['column4'] ? $data[$x]['column4'] : 0)."</td><td>".($data[$x]['column5'] ? $data[$x]['column5'] : 0)."</td></tr>";
} 

print($html_body);

In this above example, I assumed you have to get all product data in one array

Comment: @ZaheerAhmad yes I have all the data in one array because i need to take data from SQL query.

result of my query is:

nomeProdotto | Tempo 1 | Fase      |
Prodotto 1       | 1000      | Taglio     |
Prodotto 1       | 2000      | Cucito    |
Prodotto 2       | 3000      | Stiratura |

I want display this

Prodotto    | Taglio | Cucito | Stiratura | Lavaggio | Cucito a mano |
Prodotto 1 | 1000  | 2000   |    0          |     0         |   0                    |
Prodotto 2 |     0    |    0      | 3000       |     0         |   0                    |

Comment: With this image is clearer==>http://i67.tinypic.com/2ni5nyf.png

Comment: according to your data in product1 have tempo1 => 1000 and Fase => taglio  right?
now set the condition if(!empty(Fase) && Fase === taglio){ echo Fase;} else { echo 0; }

now apply this condition to all of your rows I hope it helps you understand.

Comment: in my data I can have 1 or more product (Product 1, Product 2.....Product n) every product have 1 or more Fase (Taglio, Cucito, Stiratura ecc....)
every fase have a tempo (Taglio==>tempo: 1000, Cucito==>tempo: 2000 ecc)
I want to display every Fase with her tempo for any product in one row for product. 
Excuse me  if I have not explained well.

Comment: In your data loop how you get all value against one product1?

Comment: I use a json because I extract my data from a query SQL and this is the result of my query===>http://i68.tinypic.com/16lxwmp.jpg

Comment: first set data array against your data like in the first array product1 have all Fase then use a loop for each array loop and use my above function.

Comment: sorry @ZaheerAhmad I don't have understand, can please you take me an example?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmad I tried to implement your solution but I did not succeed. Can you write me an example please?

Comment: can you share with me your code it help me out to give you clear guideline

Comment: how can I share my code with you? @ZaheerAhmad

Comment: I have update part of my code in 2 file in my dropbox, this is the link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/54iupwb1yer40wz/AABxgM5RC_5GzSOr0Wwd7JAFa?dl=0

thank you for help

Comment: @ZaheerAhmad do you have download my code from dropbox?

Comment: Hi @ZaheerAhmad can you help me please?

Comment: sorry I's on vacations, just start today. I downloaded your code tonight will check and update you here :)

Comment: thank you, I'm sorry for desturbing you from your vacations @ZaheerAhmad